# Add an extention to the file you want to save

Tags: c++, winapi, file-extension, savefiledialog

The problem is that I need to add an extension to the file name when I save it. Solution like `outfile.open(filename + ".txt")` doesn't seems to work in my case. 
There is my code:

```
SaveFileDialog* saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

int saveAs(const string& outFileName)
{
    string bufFile("C:\\Windows\\tmp.XXXXXX");
    string outFile(saveFileDialog1->NewFileName);
    string line;
    string val;
    ifstream buf_stream;
    ofstream out_stream;
    buf_stream.open(bufFile.c_str());
    out_stream.open(outFile.c_str());

    if (buf_stream)  
{
    while (!buf_stream.eof())
    {

        getline(buf_stream, line);
            buf_stream >> val;
            out_stream << val<<endl;
    }

}

buf_stream.close();
out_stream.close();
remove("C:\\Windows\\tmp.XXXXXX");

    return 0;
}
```

And then I'm trying to use that construction when I want to save result I have:

```
case IDM_FILE_SAVE:
    {

        saveFileDialog1;
        saveFileDialog1->ShowDialog();
        saveFileDialog1->FilterIndex1 = 1;
        saveFileDialog1->Flags1 |= OFN_SHOWHELP;
        saveFileDialog1->InitialDir1 = _T("C:\\Windows\\");
        saveFileDialog1->Title1 = _T("Save File");

            int retval = saveAs(saveFileDialog1->NewFileName);
}
```

There is my attempt to solve problem

```
SaveFileDialog::SaveFileDialog(void)

{
    this->DefaultExtension1 = 0;
    this->NewFileName = new TCHAR[MAX_PATH + TCHAR(".txt")];
    this->FilterIndex1 = 1;
    this->Flags1 = OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT;
    this->InitialDir1 = 0;
    this->Owner1 = 0;
    this->Title1 = 0;
    this->RestoreDirectory = true;
}




     bool SaveFileDialog::ShowDialog()
    {
        OPENFILENAME ofn;

    TCHAR szFile[MAX_PATH] = "";
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = this->Owner1;
    ofn.lpstrDefExt = this->DefaultExtension1;
    ofn.lpstrFile = this->NewFileName;
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = _T("All Files\0*.*\0Text files\0*.txt");
    ofn.nFilterIndex = this->FilterIndex1;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = this->InitialDir1;
    ofn.lpstrTitle = this->Title1;
    ofn.Flags = this->Flags1;

    GetSaveFileName(&ofn);

    if (_tcslen(this->NewFileName) == 0) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why doesn't `outfile.open(filename + ".txt")` work for you?

Comment: When I'm typing this `out_stream.open(outFile.c_str() + ".txt");` VS returns me that error: 1 IntelliSense: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Comment: @RuslanMuhamadiarov You're trying to add two pointers. Leave out the ".c_str()".

Comment: Thanks buddy! I'll be glad to give vote to your comment, but sorry I can't because of too low rep^^'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With c++11** (*check your compiler flags ?*)  the [`fstream::open()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/) function works perfectly well with strings.  So no need to pass through `c_str()`. Then you can use the [`operator+`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+/) on strings as you intended:

```
buf_stream.open(bufFile);
out_stream.open(outFile);
...
outfile.open(filename + ".txt");
```

*Remark: you can immediately give the filename to the constructor of the stream when it's already known at the time you declare it. It's hence not required to call a separate `open()`.*

**If you can't use C++11**, then use a temporary string for the concatenation:

```
outfile.open (string(filename+".tst").c_str());
```

Comment: It is working now! Thanks god, I've spent several hours for trying to fixt that :(